# Declare String with Japanese characters in java

Tags: java, eclipse, string, unicode

I want to initialize a String in Java with japanese characters as below.

```
String str = "最終条件";
```

But when I type in my Eclipse Java editor, it is displayed like this

```
String str = "|||||||";
```

What should be the reason and how can i solve it?

Comment: Are that really seven bars for the four Japanese characters? Then it could be more than a font problem. What happens if you enter the characters as Unicode sequences? Are they displayed correctly in other views then, e.g. the Javadoc rendering?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried changing the text file encoding in your project properties?

Right-click on your project, click "Properties" and change "Resource" -> "Text file encoding" to "UTF-8", "Shift_JIS" or any other suitable encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the font used by the text editor to one that supports Japanese characters.
Menu: Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts -> Basic -> Text Font -> Edit

Here is a SO thread about Unicode fonts:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586503/complete-monospaced-unicode-font

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can also rely on the \u sequences for your Japanese character.
For instance, you can use a tool like http://www.snible.org/java2/uni2java.html which converts any char sequence pasted in to the text area into a Java String.