# Setting the width of the characters of a font to be uniform in java

Tags: java, printing, fonts, width

Good Day! I am currently working on a program that prints a string in the printer. I am having problems regarding the display of the string to be printed. Ideally I want the font width of every character to be uniform. The problem occurs when when other language characters are set to be displayed. I've noticed that japanese characters are larger in width than the normal characters. Can I set these japanese characters to follow the font width of the normal characters?

Example:
NNNNN
ＮＰＤ事本

Notice that the string with japanese encoding is larger in width. How can I make this string to follow the font width of my designated font? Is there a way? or is my case hopeless? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where the data is coming from and to where you are trying to print it?

Comment: The data comes from a database and I'm trying to print it directly to a printer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are such things as monospace fonts, where each character takes the same width. I do not know if Japanese has such a font, or if there are English fonts and Japanese fonts that are both monospace and have the same width in pixels.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586503/complete-monospaced-unicode-font

The above question was closed as "off-topic" but it has some good links. The general consensus  seemed to be you are either hosed, or in for a nightmare of working with different fonts in the same document.

Comment: Ooh I see, I tried using the fonts in the links but failed to find one that will serve the purpose of what im looking for. Thanks though!