# <pre> not consistently monospace with braille characters

Tags: css, unicode, fonts

I am attempting to draw a cube using the [Braille Patterns Unicode Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille_Patterns), via the [node-drawille](https://github.com/madbence/node-drawille) library.

However, it appears that **the width of the braille characters is not consistent(?)**, even though the text is in a `<pre>` element.

I have included the demo, which prints the length of each line (80 characters). I have also included a picture of what I see when I highlight the entire `<pre>` element. (OSX 10.12)

I have tested both with the default `monospace` and the font I use in my terminal (`Menlo Regular`). The results are similar, the width is inconsistent even though the character count is the same.

[image: inconsistent widths of equal-character lines in pre element]

Desired result (pasted exactly into terminal):
[image: desired result, consistent width characters]

(For best results w/ demo, run in a full page, and highlight the entire pre element to see the variable widths).

```js
var data = document.getElementById('cube').innerHTML;
data.split('\n').forEach(x => console.log(x.length))
```

```html
<pre id="cube">
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                        ⢀⡀                                      
                                    ⢀⡠⠔⠊⠁⡏⠑⠤⡀                                   
                                ⢀⡠⠔⠊⠁    ⡇  ⠈⠑⠤⡀                                
                            ⢀⡠⠔⠊⠁        ⡇     ⠈⠑⠤⡀                             
                           ⢸⠑⠒⠤⠤⣀⡀       ⡇    ⢀⣀⡠⠤⠜⢳                            
                           ⢸     ⠈⠉⠒⠒⠤⢄⣀⡠⡧⠔⠒⠊⠉⠁    ⢸                            
                           ⢸           ⡇ ⡇         ⢸                            
                           ⢸           ⡇ ⡇         ⢸                            
                           ⢸           ⡇ ⡇         ⢸                            
                           ⢸           ⡇ ⡇         ⢸                            
                           ⡏           ⡇ ⡇          ⡇                           
                           ⡇           ⡇ ⡇          ⡇                           
                           ⡇           ⡇ ⡇          ⡇                           
                           ⡇           ⡇ ⡇          ⡇                           
                           ⡇       ⣀⡠⠤⠔⠓⠢⡧⠤⣀⣀⣀      ⡇                           
                           ⡇⣀⣀⠤⠔⠒⠋⠉      ⡇   ⠈⠉⠉⠑⠒⠒⣤⠇                           
                           ⠉⠒⠤⢄⡀         ⡇     ⢀⡠⠔⠉                             
                               ⠈⠉⠒⠦⢄⣀    ⡇  ⣀⠤⠚⠁                                
                                     ⠉⠒⠢⢄⡧⠔⠊                                    
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                
                                                                                </pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your visualizations aren't rendering properly is that your spaces and braille characters aren't the same width.

Instead of using a font to make your braille characters uniform width as your non-braille characters, you should use a different 'space' character that's the same width as your braille characters.

In your visualizations, use the empty braille character (⠀) instead of the space character and your visualization should work as expected.

Just a quick proof of concept (it's a crude smiley face):

⠀⠀⠀⣿⠀⣿⠀

⣿⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣿

⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿

This works because all braille characters are the same width.

https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/braille_patterns/utf8test.htm character 0x00

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the empty braille character, the following example will fail to render correctly.

https://pastebin.com/M61XmTkq

Answer (score 0):

It seems the answer is the same as [How to display special unicode characters using monospace font in HTML with preserved character width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351689/how-to-display-special-unicode-characters-using-monospace-font-in-html-with-pres?rq=1)

The font does not contain this block of Unicode characters, so it is rendered with a more default system font, which is not unicode. Picking a font that contains these characters, like http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html or https://github.com/josuah/miniwi fixes the issue!