# Displaying Arabic characters in C# console application

Tags: c#, unicode, console-application, arabic

I believe it was possible to show Arabic characters on a console application 13+ years ago, since the days of Windows ME.

Now i am using Visual Studio 2013, On a Windows 8, and the following code shows:

> ????? ??

```
   Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
   Console.WriteLine("مرحبا بك");
```

Is there anyway to show Arabic characters in the console output?

Comment: This worked 13+ years ago because there wasn't yet a Console class to screw this up :)  It goes wrong because you changed the OutputEncoding.  Don't touch it, it should be set to an Arabic code page on an Arabic machine.  Or utf8.  On a non-Arabic machine, you'll have trouble finding a font for the console that's capable of displaying the glyphs.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are several issues to resolve to get this to work.

- You need a font that supports both Arabic ***AND*** the windows console.

See KB : [Necessary criteria for fonts to be available in a command window](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;Q247815)

> ```
> The font must be a fixed-pitch font.
> The font cannot be an italic font.
> The font cannot have a negative A or C space.
> If it is a TrueType font, it must be FF_MODERN.
> If it is not a TrueType font, it must be OEM_CHARSET.
> ```

- You must install the font.

For testing, I used [DejaVu Mono](https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/), which is one of the few that supports Arabic.  Arabic is a tough language to make a monotype font with since the aesthetics of the language do not work well with a fixed width for each character.  Nevertheless, this font makes an honest effort.  For other possible alternatives, see :

[complete, monospaced Unicode font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586503/complete-monospaced-unicode-font)

The font must be installed in the normal way for your version of Windows (in Vista/7/8 this is `right-click, Install` on the .ttf file).  Once this is done, you have to follow the directions in the KB.

1. Registry Editor --> HKLM\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont
2. Add a new string value named "`000`" with the value `DejaVu Sans Mono`
3. Reboot

[image]

Once you've rebooted, you can change the font in the console by selecting "Properties" from the console menu and changing the font in the "Font" tab.

[image][image]

Result.

[image]

... so after all that, we discover that the [console does not support Right-To-Left languages.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9d2b0zt.aspx)  I guess you could use a function like :

```
static string Reverse(string text)
{
   if (text == null) return null; 
   char[] array = text.ToCharArray();
   Array.Reverse(array);
   return new String(array);
}
```

and then do

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
Console.WriteLine(Reverse("مرحبا بك"));
```

[image]

Comment: The remaining issues with the Arabic text should be addressed with the proper shaping algorithm.

Comment: The link you gave for "console does not support Right-To-Left languages.", actually states "Console applications do not include text support for **bi-directional languages**." which is something very different (e.g. Mixing English (LTR) and Arabic (RTL). It says nothing about not supporting Right-To-Left languages such as Arabic.

Comment: @skomisa The documentation has changed since this was answered four years ago.  The meaning is still the same - console does not support text output other than left-to-right.  Microsoft's terminology in the new documentation is a bit sloppy - by "bi-directional" they mean languages that are input other than left-to-right.

Comment: @J... Actually I was quoting from an older version of the document you linked to from the drop list it provided, and that part hasn't changed. But if you are correct Microsoft are being more than sloppy since "bi-directional" and RTL have very precise and qualitatively different meanings. Apart from all that, it would mean that Windows users using Arabic (or Persian or Hebrew or Urdu) couldn't use the Command Prompt window. That seems highly unlikely, though I admit I don't know for sure.

Comment: @skomisa It's more than likely - it's true.  The console has never supported RTL languages.  English bias was pretty much the norm in computer systems for decades - it's only relatively recently that things have been changing.

Comment: The text can be reversed and also splits the way it should be shown using [online tools](http://amib.ir/weblog/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/persian_writer.html) to something like this ` ﮏﺑ ﺎﺒﺣﺮﻣ` , so the result be more like `مرحبا بک` than `م‌ر‌ح‌ب‌ا ب‌ک`

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple asp .net core and preset your data in the browser

```
  context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
  await context.Response.WriteAsync("بسم الله الرحمن");
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Since the answer here doesn't solve your problem. I'm posting an alternate walkaround that may help for testing stuff.

If you can use a WPF project instead of a console application you'll be able to:

- View arabic text on the screen.
- Scroll over the entire output of your execution
- Easily copy the output
- Keep using C# as a coding language

Create a WPF project and add a multiligne textBox to your WPF design that has the following properties:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AcceptsReturn="True"
             TextAlignment="Right"
             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

TextAlignment to right as in arabic, VerticalScrollBarVisibility to view all the output and AcceptsReturn to have a multiline textBox. The HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment set to stretch to fill all the displayed window.

You could add a method in the code section to ease the adding of String in this textBox, the method could be like this:

```
    private void writeToTextBox(string textToWrite)
    {
        textBox1.Text += textToWrite + "\n";
    }
```

The global code behing would be:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        createSourateFromXML();

    }
    private void createSourateFromXML()
    {
        string xmlquranfile = @"C:\Users\hp\Downloads\quran-simple.xml";

        XmlDocument xml_quran = new XmlDocument();
        xml_quran.Load(xmlquranfile);
        foreach (XmlNode soura in xml_quran.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
        {
            writeToTextBox(soura.Attributes["name"].Value);
        }
    }
    private void writeToTextBox(string textToWrite)
    {
        textBox1.Text += textToWrite + "\n";
    }
}
```

The foreach loops over names in my xml file and adds them to the WPF textBox.
This is a screenshot of the execution result https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIdOY.png

You can tune the display by changing the textBox properties, things like font, style, size are all customizable.