# Printing all Bengali or Hindi or any Unicode characters in visual studio 2010 with C# console

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, console

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and I want to print Unicode characters in it console mode ([Bengali Unicode Characters](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0980.pdf)).

I am compressing database content in console, and I need to print it in console to test my exact compressed/decompressed data. But the output is three garbage characters:

[image]

Here's the code. I also tried (`Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8`).

```
using System;
using System.Text;
namespace Unicode_Printing_in_console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char ch = 'আ';// hex value=0985
            Console.WriteLine(ch);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output of this program:

[image]

Comment: What's the result so far? Did u get any errors?

Comment: The answer is a question mark(?). But I need to see the character. For my compressed or decompressed data to be tested. @AlexJolig Help me please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying Arabic characters in C# console application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751827/displaying-arabic-characters-in-c-sharp-console-application)  Note that this question refers to Arabic characters, and the LTR writing direction issues do not apply, but the solution is generally the same.

Comment: @Muhammad - for binary data, you usually [Hex Encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) it when you want to view/dump it. So the byte 0x12 is printed as the two-character ASCII string "12".

Answer (score 2):

The primary issue with Unicode languages in the Windows console is that font support is limited (among other things) to monospace fonts.  This answer details the steps to installing a new font for availability in the Windows Console :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21753872/327083

Specific to this question is the content of Bengali characters.  For full coverage, downloading and installing something like `GNU Unifont` would give 100% coverage of the Bengali block.

[GNU Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html)

Comment: Arial Unicode MS is neither a Windows font (it belongs to Office), nor is it monospaced, so you shouldn't really use it in the console. Furthermore, Arial Unicode MS is a *fallback* font, intended to show *something* when no useful font exists. It has severe issues with several languages.

Comment: @Joey My mistake.  I must have glanced at Arial's type foundry (which is named "Monospace") and got my wires crossed.  MS = Microsoft, not MonoSpaced.  The GNU font is probably the better choice in any case, and it is monospaced.