# check if Uppercase function will work

Tags: c#, string, cultureinfo, uppercase, culture

How can i detect that  ToUpper() function is possible on this string ?
By example when the language of input don't have a upper case.
I have this :

```
String text = "لان يقوم غينيا انتصا";

Console.WriteLine(text.ToUpper(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture));
```

and the output is : `"???? ????? ????"`

I tried this `Console.WriteLine(text.ToUpper(new CultureInfo("ar")));` but the result is the same as previously.

Comment: does `Console.WriteLine(text)` print the characters? I thought ToUpper ignored unmapped chars. In other words, perhaps your console window doesn't have the font or locale to correctly display that string

Comment: It's not the `ToUpper()` that's causing the problem. [See here for more info.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751827/displaying-arabic-characters-in-c-sharp-console-application)

Comment: When I run this in LinqPad, it works as expected.

Comment: @CamBruce Try it in a console app; it won't work.

Comment: I tried on dotnetfiddle.net and it works :)

Comment: @Neyoh Do you really have to have this working in a console? You'll be in a world of pain, because the console doesn't support right-to-left languages!

Comment: To prove that `.ToUpper()` is not the problem, just doing `Console.WriteLine(text);` fails in the exact same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is right, exept for your text. The console can only print ASCII chars.
A table of all chars you can use: http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif
This is because the font that the console use.
If you change the incompatible font to a compatible, it will work.