# How read form file Text language Arabic

Tags: c#, text

I have a text file that contains a single word but it is with  language : Arabic
I want to extract it

My code is:

```
 string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\CINPROCESSING\nom.txt");
 Console.WriteLine(text );
```

I have the result with unknown characters : ????

How i can fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: 1) Use GetEncoding(int codepage) and set right codepage. or 2) Save your file as UTF-8 in notepad. UTF-8 encoding worked propertly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code reads the text correctly into the variable `text`. (Debug and See)

However, dispalying arabic characters in the windows Console is another issue (Check how to solve it [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751827/displaying-arabic-characters-in-c-sharp-console-application))

Comment: Very thanks!!
I check the URL, and i find the solution

Answer (score 3):

Setup right *codepage* for your text.

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\CINPROCESSING\nom.txt",System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(codepage))
```

May be codepage=1256 (windows-arabic).

Comment: And check Console.WriteLine("arabic م") may be http://stackoverflow.com/a/38305257/5727271 right and you must change console codepage.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this:**
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\CINPROCESSING\nom.txt",Encoding.Default);
Console.WriteLine(text);

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the encoding using this StreamReader constructor:

```
StreamReader arabic_reader = new StreamReader(filePath, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true);
```

OR

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\CINPROCESSING\nom.txt",Encoding.UTF8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true);
```

For reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143457.aspx