# How to show Arabic in C++

Tags: c++, arabic

I am stuck here, as I want to write a simple program that shows Arabic writing on the output console. I have tried many times but I always ended up with strange output. I Use Windows 7 Home premium and the CodeBlocks Compiler.

Please check the code I wrote below; how can I improve it?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    cout<<"محمد ذهب الي السوق\n"<<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: what console you use?

Comment: Arabic isn't ASCII. You'll need to print Unicode characters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015571/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-c

Comment: The answer depends on the operating system, and how the output console is configured.

Comment: i use CodeBlocks oon windows 7 Home premium.

Comment: codeblocks is an IDE which uses some compiler to give you the binary output. Those things have no relation whatsoever to the console output. [Displaying Arabic characters in C# console application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21751827/995714)